# Inserting into table a number of rows that equal the number of open rows if there are more than 15 of them

Tags: sql, hive

My table

```
id    sum    type
1     3      -1   
1     6      -1    
1     -6      2   
1     -3      1   
1     3      -1
1     6      -1
```

These

```
1     3      -1
```

are open rows. Type is always -1. sum can be different.

These

```
1     -6      2
```

are closed rows. Type != -1. sum = -sum for open row

these rows

```
1     3      -1   
1     6      -1    
1     -6      2   
1     -3      1
```

will negate each other. These

```
1     3      -1
1     6      -1
```

Will remain. If the number of open rows in the end is more than 15, then for each open row I need to insert into the table a row where sum is -sum of the open row and type is 2.

Grouping

```
select id
, sum
, sum(
  case 
  when type = -1 then 1
  when type != -1 then -1
  else 0
  end
) as num
from table
group by id, sum

    id    sum    num
    1     3      2
    1     6      2    
    1     -6      2   
    1     -3      1
```

might help me find the combinations. But I don't know what to do after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      t.val_id
           ,t.val_sum  
           ,2           as val_type

from       (select      val_id
                       ,-abs (val_sum)                                   as val_sum   
                       ,sum (case when val_type = -1 then 1 else -1 end) as occurrences

            from        mytable

            group by    val_id
                       ,abs (val_sum)

            having      sum (case when val_type = -1 then 1 else -1 end) > 15
            ) t
            lateral view  explode (split (space (cast (occurrences as int) - 1),' ')) e
 ;
```